# change one value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array with objects `users`:

```
let state = {
  users: [
    {id: 1, name: 'Igor',  selected: false},
    {id: 2, name: 'Anton', selected: false},
    {id: 3, name: 'Vasya', selected: false},
    {id: 4, name: 'Pete',  selected: false},
    {id: 5, name: 'Dan',   selected: false}
  ], ....
```

And a function that works with this object:

```
export function selectUser(userId) {
  if (state.users.find(item => item.id == userId).selected == false) {
    /* some code */

    //[needed] Code to update the user property selected to true

  } else {
    /* some other code */

    //[needed] Code to update the user property selected to true
  }
  emitChange();
}
```

How to do that, without overwriting the whole array, strangely can't think of anything

Comment: Please label with the language being used.  It looks like JavaScript, but then again Pepsi looks like Coke but I would never want to drink Pepsi.

Comment: "How to do that", How to do __what__?

Comment: when you say change you mean you want to replace or modify existing object ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for that

Comment: @ikffs Your code makes no sense as the true case is the same as the false case according to the comments. Please rework your question.

Comment: @Bek I think modify. I need to toggle property "selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to toggle property then

```
export function selectUser(userId) {
  var user = state.users.find(user => user.id == userId);
  var isSelected = user.selected; 
  // state.users.forEach(user => user.selected = false ); deselect others 
  user.selected = !isSelected;
  emitChange();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The find() method returns the object you want to update.  So call that first and assign it to a variable, then test it exists and if so then work with it.

```
export function selectUser(userId) {
  var user = state.users.find(item => item.id == userId);

  if (user != 'undefined'){
    if (user.selected == false) {
      /* some code */

      user.name = 'New Name';
      // etc

    } else {
      /* some other code */
    }
  }

  emitChange();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments in the true and false case this should work:

```
export function selectUser(userId) {
  var user = state.users.find(item => item.id == userId);
  if (user && user.selected == false) {
    user.selected = true;
  } else {
    /* some other code */
  }
  emitChange();
}
```

Comment: find() returns new object, so you are modifying "user"  in your code not original object

Comment: @ikffs Where did you get that information? According to the specs Array.find() returns the object itself, not a copy or something like that. I've also tested it and it works.

Comment: jeez buddy, you are a lifesaver, sorry for long response, I don't know why but I really thought that find returns some other object, silly me! thanks